# Trigger (Flip-flop) with under 3 ns delay?

Tags: flipflop, counter, high-frequency, clock-speed

I want to make nanosecond clock timer as a 64-bit counter.
There is a scheme (4-bit):
[image]

I am trying to find JK-trigger, or other, that can work with 300 Mhz clock speed, at least, i.e. 3.3 ns at most, but I am finding only ICs with tens or even hundreds nanoseconds precision, like HCF4027BE.

Do JK (or other triggers) with less than 3.3ns delay exist?

Is there other solutions for nanosecond counter?

---

I found out about ECL logic, that seems to be fast.

How about make own triggers (flip-flops), from ECL components?

---

Well, seems like there are stuff, I need

[enter link description here](https://eu.mouser.com/c/semiconductors/logic-ics/flip-flops/?propagation%20delay%20time=95%20ps%7E%7E3.8%20ns%20at%203.3%20V&rp=semiconductors%2Flogic-ics%2Fflip-flops%7C%7EPropagation%20Delay%20Time)

There are, for example D-triggers (flip-flops) with less 3 ns propagation time.

I can use, for example, [this one](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/NL17SZ74_D-2318301.pdf) for 64-bit counter with D-trigger, right?

Comment: Use a *parametric search* with some major manufacturers. Don't forget to look for *counters* as well as bare flip flops.

Comment: (One alternative to *ripple counters* are *synchronous counters*. A by-10 prescaler is easy with a *Johnson counter*.)

Comment: @greybeard, distributors often just put IC title, like HCF4027BE, instead of full specification, or at least pointing that it is a JK-trigger

Comment: @greybeard, can You please tell how the value I am asking about is in English. I mean trigger delay, how it called correctly?

Comment: Problem: I don't know what a *trigger delay* may be. Clock input to output? Clock cycle length? 300 MHz makes a somewhat challenging *clock frequency*, compare to device's *maximum clock frequency* \$f_{max}\$.

Comment: @greybeard, I mean how long it takes to trigger, or complete counter to read a pulse and increment, i.e. the minimum clock pulse duration.

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd Greybeard is recommending you use a parametric search, not just searching by the part number. All major distributors (Digikey, Mouser, Farnell, etc) have one, and it's exactly what you need for this.

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd "Trigger" could mean several things: the propagation delay from clock input to output(s); the timing aperture between clock and inputs (setup and hold); the timing from async inputs to output(s); etc. These are all listed as such (and diagrams are usually provided) in device datasheets.

Comment: You may also find more variety to choose from if you drop the JK type requirement.  Type RS and D flip-flops are more general / common since the... gosh, I want to say JKs fell out of vogue in the 70s easily?

Comment: FWIW, with Nexperia I found D flip-flops fast enough, but neither JK flip-flops nor ("TTL type") counters.

Comment: The counter is made of 4 FFs.  It is a ripple counter that is slow.  The output is not stable until four clock delays in time have passed.  Choose a counter where "CLK" goes to all 4 FFs.  It will respond much faster.

Comment: @ronsimpson You mean asynchronous counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dedicated counters or JK flip-flops can be found only in older CMOS families, which are slow. For the shortest propagation delays, you have to look for D flip-flops in modern low-voltage families like AUC, e.g., [SN74AUC74](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74AUC74) with 350 MHz (with a 2.5 V supply).